How to choose proper value of maxConnectionAge in LDAPConnectionPool?
There is class LDAPConnectionPool
  // The maximum length of time in milliseconds that a connection should be
  // allowed to be established before terminating and re-establishing the
  // connection.
  private volatile long maxConnectionAge;

As far as I understand it is 0 by default and it means that connections won't be recreated at all.
So my question is:
How can I can I choose maxConnectionAge ? should I ? What criterias should be condered ?
